# How to incorporate tidy models PCA into the workflow of a model and make predictions

Tags: r, pca, prediction, tidymodels

I am trying to incorporate tidy models PCA into the workflow of a model. I want to have a predictive model that uses PCA as a preprocessing step and then make predictions with that model.

I have tried the following approach,

```
diamonds <- diamonds %>%
  select(-clarity, -cut, - color)

diamonds_split <- initial_split(diamonds, prop = 4/5)

diamonds_train <- training(diamonds_split)
diamonds_test <- testing(diamonds_split)

diamonds_test <-vfold_cv(diamonds_train)

diamonds_recipe <- 
  # La fórmula básica y todos los datos (outcome ~ predictors)
  recipe(price ~ ., data = diamonds_train) %>%
  step_log(all_outcomes(),skip = T) %>%
  step_normalize(all_predictors(), -all_nominal()) %>% 
  step_pca(all_predictors())

preprocesados <- prep(diamonds_recipe)

linear_model <- 
  linear_reg() %>%
  set_engine("glmnet") %>%
  set_mode("regression")

pca_workflow <- workflow() %>%
  add_recipe(diamonds_recipe) %>%
  add_model(linear_model)

lr_fitted_workflow <-  pca_workflow %>%  #option A workflow full dataset
  last_fit(diamonds_split)

performance <- lr_fitted_workflow %>% collect_metrics()

test_predictions <- lr_fitted_workflow %>% collect_predictions()
```

But I get this error:

**x Resample1: model (predictions): Error: `penalty` should be a single numeric value. ...
Warning message:
“All models failed in [fit_resamples()]. See the `.notes` column.”**

Following other tutorials I tried to use this other approach, but I don't know how to use the model to make new predictions, because the new data comes in the original (non-pca) form. So I tried this:

```
pca_fit <- juice(preprocesados) %>%  #option C no work flow at all
  lm(price ~ ., data = .)

prep_test <- prep(diamonds_recipe, new_data = diamonds_test)

truths <- juice(prep_test) %>%
          select(price)

ans <- predict(pca_fit, new_data = prep_test)

tib <- tibble(row = 1:length(ans),ans, truths)

ggplot(data = tib) +
  geom_smooth(mapping = aes(x = row, y = ans, colour = "predicted")) +
  geom_smooth(mapping = aes(x = row, y = price, colour = "true"))
```

And it prints something that seams reasonable, but by this point I have lost confidence and some guidance would be much appreciated.  :D

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in your recipe or the workflow. As described in [chapter 7 of TidyModels with R](https://www.tmwr.org/models.html) the function for fitting your model is `fit` and for it to work you'll have to provide the data for the fitting process (here `diamonds`). The tradeoff is that you don't have to `prep` your recipe as the workflow will take care of this itself.

So reducing your code slightly, the example below will work.

```
library(tidymodels)
data(diamonds)
diamonds <- diamonds %>%
  select(-clarity, -cut, - color)

diamonds_split <- initial_split(diamonds, prop = 4/5)

diamonds_train <- training(diamonds_split)
diamonds_test <- testing(diamonds_split)

diamonds_recipe <- 
  # La fórmula básica y todos los datos (outcome ~ predictors)
  recipe(price ~ ., data = diamonds_train) %>%
  step_log(all_outcomes(),skip = T) %>%
  step_normalize(all_predictors(), -all_nominal()) %>% 
  step_pca(all_predictors())

linear_model <- 
  linear_reg() %>%
  set_engine("glmnet") %>%
  set_mode("regression")

pca_workflow <- workflow() %>%
  add_recipe(diamonds_recipe) %>%
  add_model(linear_model)

pca_fit <- fit(pca_workflow, data = diamonds_train)
```

As for crossvalidation one has to use `fit_resamples` and should split the training set and not the testing set. But here I am currently getting the same error (my answer will be updated if i figure out why)

## Edit

Now I've done a bit of digging, and the problem with crossvalidation stems from the engine being `glmnet`. I am guessing that of the many different aspects this one has somehow been missed. I've added a [possible issue](https://github.com/tidymodels/workflows/issues/79#issue-714160337) to the `workflows` package github site. Often the answers are quick in coming, so likely one of the developers will come with a reply soon.

As for crossvalidation, assume you instead fit using any of the other engines described in `?linear_reg` then we could do this as

```
linear_model_base <- 
  linear_reg() %>%
  set_engine("lm") %>%
  set_mode("regression")
pca_workflow <- update_model(pca_workflow, linear_model_base)
folds <- vfold_cv(diamonds_train, 10)
pca_folds_fit <- fit_resamples(pca_workflow, resamples = folds)
```

and in the case where metrics are of interest these can indeed be collected as you did using `collect_metrics`

```
pca_folds_fit %>% collect_metrics()
```

If we are interested in the predictions you'll have to tell the model that you want to save these during the fitting process and then use `collect_predictions`

```
pca_folds_fit <- fit_resamples(pca_workflow, resamples = folds, control = control_resamples(save_pred = TRUE))
collect_predictions(pca_folds_fit)
```

Note however that the output from this is the predictions from each `fold` as you are literally fitting 10 models.

Usually crossvalidation is used to compare multiple models or tuning parameters (eg. random forest vs linear model). The best model on crossvalidation performance (`collect_metrics`) would then be selected for use and the `test` dataset would be used to get the evaluation of this models accuracy.
This is all described in [TMwR chapter 10 & 11](https://www.tmwr.org/compare.html)